# Problem with IIS with Multi ColdFusion Server Configuration

Tags: coldfusion

This is a multi ColdFusion configured server with cf7 and cf8 and the jrun located in the main C:\ .

After editing the JVM.config and increasing the  memory size to Xms1024m Xmx1024m 
and GC to XX:MaxPermSize=256m, and then restarting.

I am unable to get any of my sites to load in the browser.  One gives me a 404 and the other gives me an ACL 403 (Access Denied). If I try browse the site with the 403 to a subdirectory (ex.http://site.com/folder), I see the CFML code.  If I do the same with the site giving me the 404, I get The request is not supported.

This server originally had CF7 and then CF8 was installed in Multiserver Config.
I can get to the CF8 Admin on port 8300 but nothing on port 80 with IIS.

I returned the JVM.config file back to its default by taking the back up file and restoring to the directory, but that didn't work.

Comment: Belongs on serverfault ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I solved the issue.  The issue was that the Server orignally used a Multiserver configuration because CF 7 and CF 8 are both installed on the machines.  When I looked at the MultiServer Configuration for CF 8, everything seemed correct. However, when I looked at the Single Server CF 8 configuration there was no configuration.  Although the this type of scenario worked worked prior, I decided to add configurations to the Single CF 8 configuration and both sites came up.

Comment: You should accept your answer (which you can do after it's been 48 hours)

Answer (score 0):

These are guesses, but...

1. Has "index.cfm" been removed from the list of default documents?
2. Perhaps the CF connector needs to be re-run.

Comment: Thanks Everett for responding.  The index.cfm is still there as a list of default documents but the error still occurs.  How would I go about restarting CF Connector without restarting CF server?

Comment: The connector option is usually available in the CF start menu group.

Comment: Thanks Peter, is this the connector that is in the bin directory of the ColdFusion root.